# Make Postal Code un required for Ireland in Magento

Tags: magento

I have Magento 1.7.0.0 intalled on my server. I am facing an issue regarding optional postal code country. I mean I want to make postal/zip code optional for Ireland, for this I have selected Ireland in the list of Optional countries in the Admin Panel (System > Configuration > General). But when I visit the checkout page and select Ireland, it removes an asterisk from the Zip/Postal Code field it's fine but when I click on Continue, It shows an alert box ("Zip/Postal Code is a Required value"). Why?
Please help me! Thanks in advance...

Comment: You'd compare your theme implementation with the base theme. The front-end related code is a JavaScript code with shippingRegionUpdater. Take care of all the related label and input.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks is becuase the postal code input has the html class required-entry if you edit the template and quit the class js will not check that input and the alert will not be triggered. But remember use a conditional or something to quit this class only for Ireland.

Answer (score 0):

## Short term solution

Add this to your `.document(ready)`. Note the `*` is required as you have `country_id`, `billing[country_id]`, etc.

```
function require_postcode_check(){
    jQuery('select[name*=country_id]').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('form').find('input[name*=postcode]').toggleClass('required-entry', jQuery(this).val() != 'IE');
    });
}
require_postcode_check(); // execute on document ready
jQuery('select[name*=country_id]').on('change', function(){
    require_postcode_check(); // execute on country change
});
```

## Long-term solution

A long-term solution would be to have a class for each `<option>` that requires a postcode:

```
<option value="UK" class="postcode-required">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="IE" class="">Ireland</option>
```

Then if the `<select>` is changed, check if the selected option `hasClass('postcode-required')`.